# JS error "hX_6 is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jsf, ibm-rad, ibm-jsf

I'm using RAD 7.5.6, and JSF 1.2, and IBM JSF client framework (the `hx` taglib).

I have a search page, where within a list of items, I can edit my selected item.
When I click on the item, I'm redirected to the insert page, with all my items data.
My page is load with all the data, but I got a JS error, what I tracked to the following code, with the message "hX_6 is not defined":

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" language="JavaScript">
    if (hX_6) hX_6.setResourceServer("/APHP0000_Web/.ibmjsfres");
    if (hX_6 && hX_6.setLocale) hX_6.setLocale("pt_BR");
</script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/APHP0000_Web/.ibmjsfres/hxclient_be_v3_1_4.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    hX_6.onPageLoad();
</script>
```

This error affects my menu and all the other JS and submissions of the page.

Comment: Are you really redirecting as you say, or are you actually merely navigating (forwarding)? If just navigating, are you performing this synchronously or asynchronously (by ajax)? This kind of problem is explainable if you're navigating by ajax, but not if you're redirecting (regardless of ajax). And yes, one of the solutions is to perform a *real* redirect :)

Comment: This is the JavaScript API for IBM's JSF library. I'd check that the `.ibmjsfres` mapping is correct in your web.xml and that the `scriptCollector` tag is at the correct place in your component tree.

Comment: BalusC, thank you for the comment.
I'm simple navigating (forwarding). If I try to redirect, with de <redirect /> tag, on faces-config, I will loose my item. That is another way to do this, redirecting my page, without loosing my object?

Comment: McDowell, thanks for the comment. My libs on faces config are ok. How can I check if my scriptcollect is ok?